# Save evaluated alias command in bash/zsh history

Tags: bash, alias, zsh, evaluation

I am wondering if it would be possible to store evaluated commands in history instead of the alias. Especially with many user having their aliases it is difficult to have an overview of them when searching in history.

Example:

```
$ alias a2re="apache2ctl restart"
$ a2re
$ history
    1  a2re
```

Instead of:

```
$ history
    1 apache2ctl restart
```

Does anyone know if there is such an option for bash/zsh?

Comment: If this is to allow review of what commands users ran, better to use a system-level tool for doing that than bash history anyhow. sysdig can very efficiently record every execv() call run, which means you have every command as actually invoked -- even things not directly started via a shell.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I am aware of. `bash`, at least, records what is in the input buffer (after undergoing history expansion) just prior to hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the command. One workaround is to tell the shell to expand the line *before* you commit to executing it. After you type the alias, type <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> (where <kbd>Meta</kbd> is either your <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, depending on your setup). This will expand the line just like the shell would, but leaves the command on the command line for further editing before executing it by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then the expanded form of the command is saved in your history.

Comment: It is not entirely correct, that `bash` records the input buffer. Like `zsh` it performs *history expansion* before saving a command to history. From the *bash manpage*: *"The shell stores each command in the history list prior to parameter and variable expansion (see EXPANSION above) but after history expansion is performed"*.